# How do I use Hl7.Fhir.Rest client to search for HealthCareService's

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am completely new to FHIR and have stumbled upon this NuGet package "Hl7.Fhir.STU3" and want to use it to search for Healthcare Services as defined here: https://digital.nhs.uk/developer/api-catalogue/e-referral-service-fhir#api-Default-a010-patient-service-search.

I so far have this limited code and understand I need to pass some form of search criteria but have no idea how to proceed.  All I ever get back from the NHS client is:

*"Root object has no type indication (resourceType) and therefore cannot be used to construct an FhirJsonNode. Alternatively, specify a nodeName using the parameter."*

My code is:

```
var settings = new FhirClientSettings
        {
            Timeout = 10,
            PreferredFormat = ResourceFormat.Json,
            PreferredReturn = Prefer.ReturnMinimal,
        };

        var client = new FhirClient("https://sandbox.api.service.nhs.uk/referrals/FHIR/STU3/HealthcareService/$ers.searchHealthcareServicesForPatient", settings);
        client.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer g1112R_ccQ1Ebbb4gtHBP1aaaNM");
        client.RequestHeaders.Add("nhsd-ers-ods-code", "R69");
        client.RequestHeaders.Add("nhsd-ers-business-function", "REFERRING_CLINICIAN");
        client.RequestHeaders.Add("X-Correlation-Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        var services = client.Search<HealthcareService>();
```

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you have set as your FHIR server endpoint is actually the URL for the operation call, so that will not work. If you set the server URL to `"https://sandbox.api.service.nhs.uk/referrals/FHIR/STU3/"`, you should be able to use the FhirClient to do an operation call:

```cs
// Note that you have to send parameters in with your request, so set them up first:
var params = new Parameters();
params.Add("requestType", new Coding("https://fhir.nhs.uk/STU3/CodeSystem/eRS-RequestType-1", "APPOINTMENT_REQUEST"));
// etc...

var result = c.TypeOperation<HealthcareService>("ers.searchHealthcareServicesForPatient", params);
```

The $ sign in the original url is not part of the operation name, so I have omitted that in the request. The FhirClient will add the $ on the outgoing request.

Comment: Works a treat once I added all the require parameters.  The result is a resource of type "List".  Do you know how I convert that to a list of HealthcareService?

Comment: I had expected the result to be a Bundle, since a List only has references and not the actual resources in it. With a List, you would have to iterate over the List.entry field and use the FhirClient to get each HealthCareService resource using the reference in the entry.